# Configuring Ubuntu to Install Softwares on an Additional HDD Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, hard-drive

I have a PC with a 500GB SSD and a dual boot setup. I allocated 430GB to Windows and 70GB to Ubuntu. Now, the Ubuntu partition is full, so I added a 1TB internal HDD. I allocated 500GB to Windows and formatted the remaining 500GB as ext4. I want to instruct Ubuntu to install new software in the 500GB partition since the 70GB partition is full.
Could you please guide me on how to do this?"

Comment: Very very very bad idea: Linux is not made to break up its system onto 2 disks; if one of the two is slow to boot up it will crash your boot sequence. The Ubuntu core does not need a lot of space. I would advice to move your personal files to that partition and leave "/home/" bare (keep configs etc there but nothing else). If you want to do this you need to install software from source and compile it yourself.

Comment: Better method: format the 500Gb into NTFS (since you are still using windows). Mount the partition in /etc/fstab then move your personal files to that 500 Gb and use that as your playground. Keep /home/ as is. Makes it easy to reinstall, do maintenance and create personal backups.

Comment: Lets-move-applications-around is a classic mistake made by Windows power users. Ubuntu does not work like Windows. The advice from @Rizwind is excellent -- heed it.

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Comment: Please check this answer to a person who had a bit similar idea as you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475863/installing-ubuntu-instead-of-windows-10/1475911#1475911 . It explains the differences between how disk space is organized in Linux and Windows.

Comment: During your installation, you can choose to put your `/usr` or `/var` in the other partition

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes, theoretically you can, but it's not a very good idea, because if `/` mounts, and `/usr` or `/var` fails to mount, you basically get an unusable system. Contrary to some older systems, in current Ubuntu there is no separate `/bin` directory that contains "emergency" binaries that can be used in such case.

Comment: where I said "500" in my 2nd comment: make that the whole 1Tb. Format as ntfs or exFAT and you can use it for personal data from both systems.

Comment: You might find the question [Installing programs in root vs home partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions) and its answer useful.

Comment: Better to move /home which probably is where you are using most of the space in your 70GB. You can install and use ncdu from / or just use du from each directory to see where data is.  [Move Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455822&p=14010437#post14010437 And/or mount partitions as data partitions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk